# how to set bundler config to use system libraries whenever necessary

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I'm writing some scripts to set up development environment for a ruby app.
In my `Gemfile`, I have gems dependent on [nokogiri](https://rubygems.org/gems/nokogiri/versions/1.6.7.2), [libv8](https://rubygems.org/gems/libv8/versions/4.5.95.5) etc.

On running `bundle install` on different machines, it fails with messages like following

```rb
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

I now have this in my script to build to build native extension using system libraries.

```sh
bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
bundle install
```

I can set configurations in bundler for each gem (`bcrypt-ruby`, `libv8` etc)  a similar way.

Is there a better way to do this? Like set a flag in bundler so that bundle understand details like using system libraries and bundle install works on all platforms

Comment: I don't think bundler has a concept of options common to multiple gems

Answer (score 0):

`bundle config` by default acts as global config for machine you run it - stores data in `~/.bundle/config`

You may try to use `--local`, which stores in `your_app_dir/.bundle/config` and then commit the file or create it on deploy. I'd go with the latter

Comment: Here also I'll have to specify flags for each gems. Also can I put something in Gemfile to tell bundler these preferences?